# How to grant Azure AD application permissions between two apps without requiring admin consent?

Tags: azure-active-directory

I have two single tenant Azure AD apps A and B. App A represents a service and app B a client. I'm trying to allow B to access A with an AAD JWT token obtained using the AAD OAuth2 client credentials flow. I've defined an `appRole` in the manifest for A and am adding that as an API permission for B via `App registrations -> API Permissions -> Add a permission -> My APIs -> A -> Application permissions`

This requires admin consent even though I am the owner for both apps.

Is there a way to grant this permission without requiring an admin intervention since I own the app exposing the app role? I understand the admin consent requirement when granting permissions to access the directory which may contain sensitive user data but here it is purely a permission between two apps which I am the owner of.

The app role in the manifest for app A is as follows:

```
{
    "allowedMemberTypes": [
        "User",
        "Application"
    ],
    "description": "...",
    "displayName": "MyPermission",
    "id": "00000000-aaaa-bbbb-cccc-ddddddddddddd",
    "isEnabled": true,
    "lang": null,
    "origin": "Application",
    "value": "MyPermission"
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, this is not possible! You must grant **admin consent** when granting application permissions to the client application. Otherwise, it will prompt you "**insufficient permissions**" when you use the access token to access the api application.

You can see that when you grant your custom application permissions to the client application, `Admin consent required` is displayed as `Yes`, indicating that this is mandatory by AAD and you cannot bypass this step.

[image]

In addition, you can also view by parsing the token. Only if the admin consent the application permission, there will be `roles` claim in the token, otherwise it will not display the claim.

[image]

Comment: Thanks! Do you have any thoughts on why this admin consent is required here from a security perspective in my case of a permission between two apps, not directory resources?

Comment: @mmajis  I have consulted some documents, and Microsoft has not explained too much about it. You can put forward your suggestions in the forum: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/34192--general-feedback